# Blender doesn't open/run? How do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, blender

I used `sudo apt-get install blender` to install blender on Ubuntu 9.10

But it doesn't  open. 
When I click
Applications > Graphics > Blender (fullscreen)
or
Applications > Graphics > Blender (windowed)
nothing happens.

```
root@penelope:~# sudo apt-get install blender
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
blender is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 232 not upgraded.


root@penelope:~# blender
Compiled with Python version 2.6.4rc2.
Checking for installed Python... got it!
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:177: X11 glxChooseVisual() failed for OpenGL, verify working openGL system!
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0xb7742ec0
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem but: you are logged in into your system as `root` AND use `sudo`?

Comment: LOL..sorta overkill but I didn't think it made a difference, I was just copy-pasting the commands from a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu seems to miss accelerated 3D graphics. You need to install a decent video driver; see **System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers** if it suggests something for you already.

Comment: It says, No proprietary divers are in use on this system.